# MIPS - Accessing and altering an array of characters

Tags: arrays, char, mips, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on a tic tac toe game for a homework assignment in MIPS.

So I have an array of characters set up like so:

```
boardArray:
    .align 2
    .byte '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '-'
```

I'm attempting to access like so:

```
sll $t1,$t1,2           # multiply the index by 4
add $t2,$t4,$t1      # add the values of the address and the offset; store in $t2
lw $t3,($t2)            # store the contents of $t2 in $t3
```

With the last line replaced by:

```
sw $s1,($t2)            # store the value of $s1 in $t2
```

To alter a value in the array. However, it doesn't appear to be working. I have the player input a row and column value, then try to check that position (accessing the array) to see if it's open (if it's open it's a '_'). If it is open, then it's replaced by an 'X' or 'O' depending on the current player. I uploaded the entire program [here](http://pastebin.com/gVZ9aGpp). Please excuse how horrendous it is, assembly and I are not friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `w` in `lw`/`sw` means `word`, which is a unit of 4 bytes on MIPS. The elements in your `boardArray` are bytes, not words.

You've got a couple of alternatives: either make your array an array of words; or use `lbu`/`sb` instead of `lw`/ `sw` and skip the index scaling.